# Filter Firestore docs based on answers (bools) in survey in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, filter, boolean

I am making an app that helps you decide which country you should visit, based on answers in a survey. I have created a collection in which each doc has a map (keys) with bool-fields.

For example Collection 'Countries' - doc 'Belgium' - field 'keys.party': false

Based on the answers of the user I would like to filter the docs to come to one or more countries that fit their choices. How do I store these answers to query the docs, so I can use them on the result page in a Streambuilder? What's the best way to achieve this?

I also created a collection of users (anonymous) when the survey starts it creates a user doc. I was thinking about storing the answers in there .. and then comparing it to the Country 'collection', but I don't know how to accomplish that.

In need of advice.

Answer (score 0):

by reading your answer there are multiple ways to achieve what you want. So as I understood a user fills out a form and based on the entered data after the user submits the form a list of countries should pop up that fit the filter, correct?

First option -> Filtered database query: When the user hits submit you navigate to the next screen and before everything loads use a FutureBuilder that executes a function that makes a call to the database before the rendering process or just use a stream builder. The call going to Firebase can look something like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore
    .collection('countries')
    .where('keys.party', isEqualTo: false)
    .where(...)
    .where(...)
    .orderBy("keys.party", descending: false)
    .snapshots()
```

In the where clauses you can parse the criteria entered by your user. Firebase might spit out something that you need to create an index to search properly but it filters all the data and only returns the data that fits the criteria

Second option -> Filter locally: You can also pull all the countries from Firebase, save them to a list and then filter locally.

```
countries = documents
.where(
(country) =>
country.*yourattribute* == false,)
.toList();
```

The second option means that you first need to pull all countries from Firebase (more reads might eventually result in higher Firebase costs). I would go with option number one.

If you reopen the app and still want to query filtered countries with the old survey you of course need to store the user-entered data somewhere. I recommend a user collection with the user document and the survey answers either in a separate document in subcollection or in a user document (Just like you suggested). When opening the app again or navigating to the page where the filtered countries are shown just load the survey data before so you can pass it to the function inside the stream builder or future builder. Hope this answers your question.